# "should get show" controller test failing for Nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-resources, ruby-test

I have a `User` model and a `Shoppingcart` model where

```
# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :shoppingcart
end
```

and

```
# shopppingcart.rb
class Shoppingcart < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

and I have this in routes.rb:

```
resources :users do
    resource :shoppingcart
end
```

and in Shoppingcarts_controller.rb I have

```
class ShoppingcartsController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @user = User.find(current_user)
        @shoppingcart = @user.build_shoppingcart
    end
end
```

and within shoppingcarts_controller_test.rb:

```
require 'test_helper'
class ShoppingcartsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
    def setup
        @user = users(:michael)
    end
    test "should get show" do
        puts(@user.name) # => Michael Example
        puts(@user.id) # => 762146111
        get :show # error line
        assert_response :success
    end
end
```

But when ever I run the test I get `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with 'id'=`. When I comment out the error line the error goes away and everything works. As for the non-test code, everything works. I can reach `users/1/shoppingcart` with no issue, so the problem must be coming from the test itself. How do I make a test for an action to a nested resource?

SessionsHelper.rb:

```
module SessionsHelper

    # Returns the current logged-in user (if any).
    def current_user
        if (user_id = session[:user_id])
            @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
        elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
            user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
            if user && user.authenticated?(:remember, cookies[:remember_token])
                log_in user
                @current_user = user
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: How is current_user defined? If you can find out why it is returning nil then you'll have your answer

Comment: current_user implementation has been added here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` method requires primary key of the particular user from `Users` table, not the user itself. Primary key is `id`, so you need to change this line in your controller.

```
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
```

Comment: Now the error looks like `NoMethodError: undefined method id for nil:NilClass`

Comment: I think, that's because you don't have `current_user` in your tests, because you don't log `@user` in. I've updated the answer, it should work.

Comment: Your code is wrong but your idea is right! I wasn't logged in. I added `logged_in_as(@user)` at the end of the setup action the test class and changed that line in the controller to `@user = User.find(current_user.id)`